# Avoid Alert Dialog getting closed when back button pressed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, back

First thing I want to say, this was done by seeing a tutorial. Here is the Custom Alert Dialog activity part I am calling from a broadcast receiver. The only problem is the back button click. Once the Alert dialog activity got started, when I press the back button it is getting closed.

```
 public class AlertDialogActivity extends Activity {
    @Override 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inmsgdialog);
 }
  @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

I have tried `onBackPressed` and I'm able to see the toast message but the activity is getting closed.

Comment: super.onBackPressed(); //Remove this line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here:

```
 @Override 
public void onBackPressed() 
{ 
    super.onBackPressed(); //Remove this line 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Do not call `super.onBackPressed();` code if you want to disable back button for activity. So remove this line. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below option to handle back button press

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

       //your code
        return true;
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: i will give a try now and let u know.

Comment: You can achieve the same by removing 'super.onBackPressed()' but it may cause memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Don't propagate the event and you should be good.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    //don't call super
}
```

Comment: Cool, a few seconds earlier and I would have got all the up votes !